# Is there a complete list of available values for the `--rpcapi` command line option of geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, external-api

I known this page https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC, but seems it doesn't contains all available apis, for example, it doesn't contain `personal` API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(from https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs):

> To determine which APIs an interface provides, the modules JSON-RPC
>   method can be invoked. For example over an ipc interface on unix
>   systems:
>
> ```
> echo '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"rpc_modules","params":[],"id":1}' | nc -U $datadir/geth.ipc
> ```
>
> will give all enabled modules including the version number:
>
> ```
> {  
>    "id":1,
>    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
>    "result":{  
>       "admin":"1.0",
>       "db":"1.0",
>       "debug":"1.0",
>       "eth":"1.0",
>       "miner":"1.0",
>       "net":"1.0",
>       "personal":"1.0",
>       "shh":"1.0",
>       "txpool":"1.0",
>       "web3":"1.0"
>    }
> }
> ```